# Changing Iframe Z- index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, z-index

How can i change a z-index of the iframe. My page generates a iframe of random id and i am able to read the iframe id but not sure how can i change the z-index of the iframe which is now sets to 10000 and i want to change it to -1. This is my iframe.

```
<iframe marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="ebBannerIFrame_24907031_5179572172928602" src="http://ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingRes//Site-2/WSFolders/3006392_201//index.html?v=_2_27_1_0" allowtransparency="true" onload="(function(e) { var event = new EBG.Events.Event(EBG.Events.EventNames.ELEMENT_LOADED);event.dispatcher = this;event.eventData = { DOMEvent: e, elementId: &quot;ebBannerIFrame_24907031_5179572172928602&quot;, adUId:&quot;24907031_5179572172928602&quot; };event.timing = EBG.Events.EventTiming.ONTIME_AND_AFTER;EBG.eventMgr.dispatchEvent(event);} )(typeof arguments != &quot;undefined&quot; ? arguments[0] : null);" style="border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1400px; height: 1200px; z-index: 10000; clip: rect(auto auto auto auto); position: absolute;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Why not add a class?

Comment: i have a small script which runs in the background and generates a iframe which loads the content. So i am able to read the iframe id on my testing page now i need to change the z index using iframe id  (jquery or js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('someID').style.zIndex = -1;
```

### jQuery:

```
$('someID').css('z-index', -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<iframe marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="ebBannerIFrame_24907031_5179572172928602" src="http://ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingRes//Site-2/WSFolders/3006392_201//index.html?v=_2_27_1_0" allowtransparency="true" onload="(function(e) { var event = new EBG.Events.Event(EBG.Events.EventNames.ELEMENT_LOADED);event.dispatcher = this;event.eventData = { DOMEvent: e, elementId: &quot;ebBannerIFrame_24907031_5179572172928602&quot;, adUId:&quot;24907031_5179572172928602&quot; };event.timing = EBG.Events.EventTiming.ONTIME_AND_AFTER;EBG.eventMgr.dispatchEvent(event);} )(typeof arguments != &quot;undefined&quot; ? arguments[0] : null);" style="border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1400px; height: 1200px; z-index: -1; clip: rect(auto auto auto auto); position: absolute;"></iframe>
```

Comment: thanks but i think you did not get my point. I want to change using  jquery or javascript. I have a small script when i am placing on the html page then it generates this iframe with random id and i am able to read the id but how can i alter the the z index.